# Multidimensional array with an existing array and a const variable

Tags: php

I want to create a multidimensional array with following items: `$arr` (which is an array that contains several names) and a constant variable `$amount` (1). I need to have something like this:

```
$new = array(
    array('name1', 1),
    array('name2', 1),
    array('name3', 1),
    array('name4', 1),
    ...
);
```

It would be nice if I can make this MDA using a for or foreach loop! Thanks for helping.

Comment: Sounds like a fairly trivial thing to do. Did you try anything …?

Comment: i'm using array_merge. This returns me an error because my $amount is not an array

Comment: could you show your best attempt (code) and the sample source data that would be needed to construct the desired outcome.

Comment: So iterate over `$arr` and append values to new array. Simple, isn't it?

Comment: _“i'm using array_merge. This returns me an error because my $amount is not an array”_ - and that therefor this would not be the right function to use, didn’t occur to you from the start? This is terribly easy to solve, if you just loop over your array, and inside the loop create and assign the appropriate elements (which are again arrays), to your result array. (Of course it can be done using some of the more sophisticated array functions as well, but as a beginner, you should try the simplest version first.)

Comment: @CBroe As you said, i'm a beginner. But thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$zeroths = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
$first   = 1;
foreach($zeroths as $zeroth) {
    $result[] = [$zeroth, $first];
}

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
0 => 
array (
    0 => 'foo',
    1 => 1,
),
1 => 
array (
    0 => 'bar',
    1 => 1,
),
2 => 
array (
    0 => 'baz',
    1 => 1,
),
)
```

Comment: Perfect, that's what i needed. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

Functional approach:

```
$arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
$amount   = 1;
$new_array = array_map(
    function($v) use ($amount) { return [$v, $amount]; }, 
    $arr
);
```

Comment: `array_map(fn($v) => [$v, $amount], $arr);`.  A short arrow function is a slightly tidier alternative.

Comment: @Progrock Ithanks for `fn`, I'm not using php7.4 that's why I don't remember) As for downvoting - someone downvoted us both.